# How to get the CID number of comments from comment table?

Tags: comments

If you check the comment table, you can see taht each comment has a CID number. 
For each article I need to have the CID number of all the comments for that article.

So I have written the following in node.tpl.php file:

```
 $result=db_select('comment', 'c')
 ->fields('cid')
  ->condition('nid', $node->nid,'=');

  $record=$result->execute()->fetch();
```

But I get error. So what is my mistake?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
  $result=db_query('SELECT cid FROM comment WHERE nid = :nid',array(':nid' => $node->nid));
```

Hope this helps you.

Comment: So when I write only what you said,I will not get any error, but what should I write to execute the query? when I write $record=$result->execute()->fetch();
 it gives me error.

Comment: There is no need for "$record=$result->execute()->fetch();" put $result in foreach loop and print the result and see.

Comment: so I wrote foreach($result as $key)  echo $key; and I get this error:Recoverable fatal error: Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string in include() (line 187 of C:\xampp\htdocs\myproject\sites\all\themes\Project\templates\node.tpl.php). Do you think I can use this query in node.tpl.php ?

Comment: also if I write krumo($result), I will see this: ... (Object) DatabaseStatementBase
dbh (Object) DatabaseConnection_mysql
queryString (String, 40 characters ) SELECT cid FROM comment WHERE

Comment: and if I write: $result1=$result->execute(); I will get this error: PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: no parameters were bound in include() (line 187 of C:\xampp\htdocs\myproject\sites\all\themes\Project\templates\node.tpl.php).Do you know what is the problem?

Comment: I was able execute this query successfully without an errors. Please try print_r($key);

Comment: No. I don't know what is causing you the error. As I said I was able to execute this query successfully.

Comment: Yes, with print_r it worked, Thank you so much.so just one more question. so now my output is like: stdClass Object ( [cid] => 22 ) stdClass Object ( [cid] => 23 ) stdClass Object ( [cid] => 24 ) stdClass Object ( [cid] => 25 ) stdClass Object ( [cid] => 26 ) stdClass Object ( [cid] => 27 ) stdClass Object ( [cid] => 28 )  So if I want to save just those numbers(22,23,..) in array, how can I do it? @aparna

Comment: just make $key->cid into an array. Take a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2476876/how-do-i-convert-an-object-to-an-array